# Need to load data from one table to another

Tags: mysql, data-warehouse, unpivot

Initial row data is there in below table-

```
create table offer_row_data ( 
customer_key char(20), 
offer1_id char(20), 
offer1_cd char(20), 
offer1_brand_nm char(20), 
offer2_id char(20), 
offer2_cd char(20), 
offer2_brand_nm char(20), 
offer3_id char(20), 
offer3_cd char(20), 
offer3_brand_nm char(20), 
offer4_id char(20), 
offer4_cd char(20), 
offer4_brand_nm char(20)
);
```

I need to transform this and load in below table...

```
create table offer_data (
offer_key INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
offer_id char(20) NOT NULL,
offer_cd char(20) NOT NULL,
offer_brand_nm char(20));
```

here is some random data-

```
INSERT INTO offer_row_data VALUES ('1','offer_id_1a','offe3_cd_1a','offer_nm_1a','offer_id_1b','offe3_cd_1b','offer_nm_1b','offer_id_1c','offe3_cd_1c','offer_nm_1c','offer_id_1d','offe3_cd_1d','offer_nm_1d');
INSERT INTO offer_row_data VALUES ('2','offer_id_2a','offe3_cd_2a','offer_nm_2a','offer_id_2b','offe3_cd_2b','offer_nm_2b','offer_id_2c','offe3_cd_2c','offer_nm_2c','offer_id_2d','offe3_cd_2d','offer_nm_2d');
INSERT INTO offer_row_data VALUES ('3','offer_id_3a','offe3_cd_3a','offer_nm_3a','offer_id_3b','offe3_cd_3b','offer_nm_3b','offer_id_3c','offe3_cd_3c','offer_nm_3c','offer_id_3d','offe3_cd_3d','offer_nm_3d');
```

here is the solution of mine -

```
INSERT INTO offer_data (offer_id,offer_cd,offer_brand_nm) 
(SELECT distinct offer1_id, offer1_cd, offer1_brand_nm FROM offer_row_data)
UNION
(SELECT distinct offer2_id, offer2_cd, offer2_brand_nm FROM offer_row_data)
UNION
(SELECT distinct offer3_id, offer3_cd, offer3_brand_nm FROM offer_row_data)
UNION
(SELECT distinct offer4_id, offer4_cd, offer4_brand_nm FROM offer_row_data)
```

since I'm having 25 million of the dataset so it will be a performance burden and expecting a more efficient solution

Example:

Input:

```
+--------------+-------------+-------------+-----------------+-------------+-------------+-----------------+-------------+-------------+-----------------+-------------+-------------+-----------------+
| customer_key | offer1_id   | offer1_cd   | offer1_brand_nm | offer2_id   | offer2_cd   | offer2_brand_nm | offer3_id   | offer3_cd   | offer3_brand_nm | offer4_id   | offer4_cd   | offer4_brand_nm |
+--------------+-------------+-------------+-----------------+-------------+-------------+-----------------+-------------+-------------+-----------------+-------------+-------------+-----------------+
| 1            | offer_id_1a | offe3_cd_1a | offer_nm_1a     | offer_id_1b | offe3_cd_1b | offer_nm_1b     | offer_id_1c | offe3_cd_1c | offer_nm_1c     | offer_id_1d | offe3_cd_1d | offer_nm_1d     |
| 2            | offer_id_2a | offe3_cd_2a | offer_nm_2a     | offer_id_2b | offe3_cd_2b | offer_nm_2b     | offer_id_2c | offe3_cd_2c | offer_nm_2c     | offer_id_2d | offe3_cd_2d | offer_nm_2d     |
| 3            | offer_id_3a | offe3_cd_3a | offer_nm_3a     | offer_id_3b | offe3_cd_3b | offer_nm_3b     | offer_id_3c | offe3_cd_3c | offer_nm_3c     | offer_id_3d | offe3_cd_3d | offer_nm_3d     |
+--------------+-------------+-------------+-----------------+-------------+-------------+-----------------+-------------+-------------+-----------------+-------------+-------------+-----------------+
```

Expected output:

```
+-----------+-------------+-------------+----------------+
| offer_key | offer_id    | offer_cd    | offer_brand_nm |
+-----------+-------------+-------------+----------------+
|         1 | offer_id_1a | offe3_cd_1a | offer_nm_1a    |
|         2 | offer_id_2a | offe3_cd_2a | offer_nm_2a    |
|         3 | offer_id_3a | offe3_cd_3a | offer_nm_3a    |
|         4 | offer_id_1b | offe3_cd_1b | offer_nm_1b    |
|         5 | offer_id_2b | offe3_cd_2b | offer_nm_2b    |
|         6 | offer_id_3b | offe3_cd_3b | offer_nm_3b    |
|         7 | offer_id_1c | offe3_cd_1c | offer_nm_1c    |
|         8 | offer_id_2c | offe3_cd_2c | offer_nm_2c    |
|         9 | offer_id_3c | offe3_cd_3c | offer_nm_3c    |
|        10 | offer_id_1d | offe3_cd_1d | offer_nm_1d    |
|        11 | offer_id_2d | offe3_cd_2d | offer_nm_2d    |
|        12 | offer_id_3d | offe3_cd_3d | offer_nm_3d    |
+-----------+-------------+-------------+----------------+
```

Comment: Does the order of the `offer_key` really matter to you?

Comment: No, it doesn't matter. just it should load data to the target table correctly...

Comment: I can't think of a more efficient solution than what you already have, except that you might not need to use `DISTINCT`, unless you expect duplicate values.  Anyway, the `UNION` should already remove duplicates.

Comment: I also realized it a later point of time if I'm using union and it is a set operation then distinct can be skipped... but looking for some other way to do it so that it should not create any performance issues...

Comment: Well how often do you need to run this query?  As a one off thing, is your current solution a significant problem?

Comment: it will be once a week for 25M of data on 1st day and remaining days with some 100K data and again continuing in the same way in next week onwards

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - Keep in mind that `UNION ALL` is faster than `UNION` (aka `UNION DISTINCT`) since it does not need a temp table to do the de-duping.

Comment: @VipulKumar - 100K/day -- Is this a big dump from somewhere?  Can't you go back further in the dataflow and "fix" the schema earlier?  Can you get the data hourly instead of daily?

Answer (score 0):

If you use a CTE, it reads data only once instead of 4 times in your original SQL and it might be faster.

```
INSERT INTO offer_data (offer_id,offer_cd,offer_brand_nm) 
WITH offer_CTE as (SELECT * FROM offer_row_data)
(SELECT distinct offer1_id, offer1_cd, offer1_brand_nm FROM offer_CTE)
UNION
(SELECT distinct offer2_id, offer2_cd, offer2_brand_nm FROM offer_CTE)
UNION
(SELECT distinct offer3_id, offer3_cd, offer3_brand_nm FROM offer_CTE)
UNION
(SELECT distinct offer4_id, offer4_cd, offer4_brand_nm FROM offer_CTE)
```

Please let me know if this solves your performance issue.

Comment: I think you missed something. The query is giving an error, could you please reframe the same.

Comment: what is the error message? Also what I the version of your mysql? mysql started supporting CTE's after version 8

Comment: I'm using MySQL 5.7. can you help me out writing a MySQL 5.7 equivalent of above query...

Answer (score 0):

I would pick this as simple and possibly the fastest, and it works if you are not using MySQL 8.0 / MariaDB 10.2 (which have CTE):

```
INSERT INTO offer_data (offer_id,offer_cd,offer_brand_nm) 
    SELECT offer1_id, offer1_cd, offer1_brand_nm
        FROM wide_table;
INSERT INTO offer_data (offer_id,offer_cd,offer_brand_nm) 
    SELECT offer2_id, offer2_cd, offer2_brand_nm
        FROM wide_table;
INSERT ... 3...
INSERT ... 4...
```

If there are "up to 4" offers in the rows, I suggest you add this on to `SELECT` #2:

```
    WHERE offer2_id IS NOT NULL
       OR offer2_cd IS NOT NULL
       OR offer2_brand_nm IS NOT NULL
```

(And do similarly for the other selects.)

`DISTINCT` will slow things down, but do it if you need to.  Alternatively, use `INSERT IGNORE` *and* have some kind of `UNIQUE` key ready to catch dups.

You might want to rethink the need for an `AUTO_INCREMENT` on the new table.  Perhaps one of (or a combination of) the new columns could be the 'natural' `PRIMARY KEY`?

This would also be a good time to check the datatypes.  Maybe you don't need an 8-byte `BIGINT`, but could use a 4-byte `INT` or 3-byte `MEDIUMINT`.  Are the `char(20)` columns really fixed length?  Are they utf8?  `VARCHAR(20)` with a suitable `CHARACTER SET` might be *significantly* better for space *and* performance.

Once you get the table loaded, toss the old table.  It is bad practice to have an array spread across multiple columns.

Answer (score 0):

(fixing syntax error for demicioglu's Answer)

```
INSERT INTO offer_data (offer_id,offer_cd,offer_brand_nm) (
    WITH offer_CTE as (SELECT * FROM offer_row_data)
  SELECT * FROM (
    (SELECT distinct offer1_id, offer1_cd, offer1_brand_nm FROM offer_CTE)
    UNION
    (SELECT distinct offer2_id, offer2_cd, offer2_brand_nm FROM offer_CTE)
    UNION
    (SELECT distinct offer3_id, offer3_cd, offer3_brand_nm FROM offer_CTE)
    UNION
    (SELECT distinct offer4_id, offer4_cd, offer4_brand_nm FROM offer_CTE)
     ) a );
```

And it is tentatively faster than my answer, which involved 4 separate inserts.  I do not know if it "reads data only once".